# streaming iText pdf directly to lotus email using xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

i'm trying to stream a newly generated pdf (using itext) directly to the body of lotus notes email as an attachment. but i'm getting following error while setting body of the email from bytes

```
"com.ibm.jscript.types.GeneratedWrapperObject$StaticField incompatible with com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSValue"
```

following is my completed code(placed in a button of an xpage). Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    session.setConvertMIME(false);

outputStream:java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
writePdf(outputStream);
var bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
var inputStream:java.io.ByteArrayInputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

var db:NotesDatabase= session.getDatabase("","mail.box")

if (!db.isOpen()) {
    print ("No mailbox!")
}
else
{
    var doc:NotesDocument=db.createDocument()
    doc.replaceItemValue("Form","Memo")
    doc.replaceItemValue("From",context.getUser().getCommonName())
    doc.replaceItemValue("Principal",context.getUser().getCommonName())
    doc.replaceItemValue("SendTo","a@b.com");
    doc.replaceItemValue("Recipients","a@b.com");
    doc.replaceItemValue("CopyTo","a@b.com");

    doc.replaceItemValue("INetFrom","b@c.com");
    var strFileName="temp.pdf"

    var body:NotesMIMEEntity = doc.createMIMEEntity('Body');
    var hdr:NotesMIMEHeader = body.createHeader("Subject");
    hdr.setHeaderValAndParams("Subject")
    hdr=body.createHeader("MIME-Version")
    hdr.setHeaderValAndParams("1.0")
    body.setPreamble("multipart message in MIME")

    var child1:NotesMIMEEntity= body.createChildEntity()

    hdr = child1.createHeader("Content-Disposition")
    hdr.setHeaderValAndParams('attachment; filename="test.pdf"')
    var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
    stream.setContents(inputStream)
    child1.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/pdf", body.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
    child1.encodeContent(body.ENC_BASE64)
    doc.closeMIMEEntities(true,"Body")

    doc.save(true, true);
    // Restore conversion
    session.setConvertMIME(true);       
}
    function writePdf(outputStream) {

    var document:com.itextpdf.text.Document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
    var writer = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(document,outputStream);

    document.open();

    document.addTitle("Test PDF");
    document.addSubject("Testing email PDF");
    document.addKeywords("iText, email");
    document.addAuthor("Author");
    document.addCreator("Creator");

    var passChunk:com.itextpdf.text.Chunk = new com.itextpdf.text.Chunk("Hello");   
    document.add(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph(passChunk));

    document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably would be better off writing a small Java wrapper class.
For starters you need:

```
   var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
   stream.setContents(inputStream);
   stream.setPosition(0);
```

so the stream is at the beginning.

**Update**:
Also you have:
<strike>var bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

var inputStream:java.io.ByteArrayInputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
stream.setContents(inputStream);</strike>
where I would write:

```
   var bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
   stream.write(bytes);
```

Still, make a helper in Java.

Note: iText is GPL licenced. Unless the application you build is internal use only, you either need to buy a commercial license or GPL your code as well. Look at [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) for an alternative

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for answering. i did the positioning of stream but still got the same error "java.lang.ClassCastException" on line child1.setContentfromByte(....  in stack trace.

Comment: Try to use a simple Java wrapper class, so you don't get sucked into the autocasting attempt of SSJS. And try to cut the stream out of your code - answer updated above

Comment: Thank you stephan. As suggested it did worked by cutting stream out of code by using java wrapper class